# ReferenceError: basket_text is not defined

Tags: javascript

Can anyone see what the problem is here? It keeps saying that the basket_text function is not defined but i don't know why?

**HTML**

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

  document.write(basket_text());

</script>
```

**first.js**

```
    function basket_text(){
  var emptyBasketHTML = "<span class='header_text'>My Bag: (0 items) Total: &#163;0.00</span>";
  var populated = "<span class='header_text'><a href='/basket'>##ITEMS##</a><br />Total: ##VALUE##</span>";
  //populated += "<input type='submit' value='Checkout' name='commit' class='go_botton header-checkout-button'>"
  populated += "<form action='/basket'>";
  populated += "<input type='submit' value='Checkout' class='header-checkout-button'>"
  populated += "</form>";
  return fc_basket_text_from_cookie(emptyBasketHTML,populated);

}
```

**second.js**

```
    function fc_basket_text_from_cookie(empty_text, normal_text)
{
  var basket = readCookie('bk');

  if (basket)
  {
    var parts = decodeURIComponent(basket.replace(/\+/g, '%20')).split('|')

    if (parseInt(parts[1]) == 0)
      return normal_text.replace(/##VALUE##/g, parts[0]).replace(/##ITEMS##/g, parseInt(parts[1]));
      // return empty_text
    else
      return normal_text.replace(/##VALUE##/g, parts[0]).replace(/##ITEMS##/g, parseInt(parts[1]));
  } else {
    return '';
  }
}

function basket_text()
 {
     return fc_basket_text_from_cookie('<span>Your basket is empty (not used?)</span>', '<span>Items in basket: ##ITEMS##</span><div><span>&nbsp;</span><span>##VALUE##</span></div>')
 }
```

Any insight is much appreciated?

Cheers

Comment: There isn't a `basket_item` function in that code for a start. So which is it - `basket_text` is undefined or `basket_item` is undefined because your question title contradicts your question body.

Comment: You are using `basket_text()` in both first.js and second.js

Comment: basket_text sorry, typo @Andy

Comment: i've removed `basket_text()` from first.js and placed it in second.js instead of the existing `basket_text()` function that's there

Comment: You aren't including either of your scripts in your HTML.

Comment: Is second.js called before the `document.write` in your html, because it needs to be (PS you should avoid document.write if possible and use more element-specific commands like `document.getElementById('basket').innerHTML = basket_text();` for example.)

Comment: Thanks all, have fixed it. Cheers